# How to add a control to a panel on a form from another user control

Tags: c#, windows

I have a form1.cs and in that form I have a panel1, in the load event of the form1.cs I am adding a control to the panel1. Now  my issue is, I have a control called Numbers.cs, I need to add another control to that panel1 but from this control in a button event. How can I do this?

```
public partial class Number : UserControl
{
    public Number()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAcceptWelcome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //HERE I NEED TO PASS A CONTROL TO THE PANEL1 IN FORM1.CS
          //NOT SURE HOW TO DO THIS.
    }
}
```

MORE INFO

So basically I have a folder called UserControls and in that folder I have

```
Numbers.cs
Letters.cs
Welcome.cs
```

All of them user controls, then i have a form

```
Form1.cs
```

Form1.cs instantiates Welcome and it is added to a Panel1 on the Form1.cs on form load. Then Welcome.cs has a button, when I click this button I need to swap to Numbers.cs. But I dont know how to do this from Welcome.cs

Comment: Is Numbers.cs being hosted in Form1 and is the control being added to your panel being created in Numbers.cs or in Form1

Comment: The way i have it is I have a form form1.cs and then in a folder i am creating user controls, but sometimes.. one of those user controls need to add a different user control to form1.cs.. so hard to explain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle stacked controls in .NET Winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327968/how-to-handle-stacked-controls-in-net-winforms)

Comment: Although there is that duplicate response, there is no cleaner way than the shown below, therefore I would think this is a better answer for someone that needs to learn to do it the proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to use a [Custom Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) raised by Numbers and handled by Form1 to pass the control and add it to your Panel's Control Collection.

---

This is an example of an Custom Event added to UserControl1

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserControl2 mySecondControl = new UserControl2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userControl11.AddControl+=new EventHandler(SwapControls);

    }

    private void SwapControls(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Remove(userControl11);
        userControl11.AddControl -= new EventHandler(SwapControls);
        panel1.Controls.Add(mySecondControl);
    }
}
```

**UserControl**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler AddControl;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AddControl(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: would it be to much to ask for a mini example.. i a baby programmer in windows forms.

Comment: @user710502 do you need to swap UserControls or add additional

Comment: i gotta clear the one currently on the form and put the new one. I have a Panel1 in form1.cs where i am putting the control

Comment: @IAbstract as you may have noticed I struck out the code in question and added code that is using my first statement. I only put the first option when it sounded like the first usercontrol was creating the second. I will remove the code totally from my answer.

Comment: why is this userControl11.AddControl+=new EventHandler(SwapControls);  giving me an object reference is required for the non static field, method or property?

Comment: @user710502 Have you compiled the changes in your UserControl? It sounds like your main Form is not seeing the new Event.

Comment: yeah weird, i added that piblic event EventHandler AddControl; to the user control.. but stil get Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ProgramTest.Viewers.Number.AddControl' C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Programs\ProgramTest\ProgramTest\Form1.cs 21 13 ProgramTest

Comment: And it underlines this Number.AddControl

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9251/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-user710502)

Answer (score 2):

Note:

1. Untested code
2. Assuming Form1 has (or can get) a reference to `Number`

Add an event handler to `Number`:

```
public partial class Number : UserControl
{
    //  event handler Form1 will subscribe to
    public EventHandler<EventArgs> OnWelcomeAccepted = (o, e) => { };

    public Number()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAcceptWelcome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //  raise the event
          OnWelcomeAccepted(sender, e);
    }
}
```

...Form1 will have a subscription **after** `InitializeComponent()`; note the additional subscription to [`ControlAdded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controladded.aspx):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ControlAdded += Control_Added;
        //  subscribe to the event and provide the implementation
        Number.OnWelcomAccepted += (o, e) => { Controls.Add(GetControl( )); }
    }

    private void Control_Added(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        //  process size and placement and show
    }

}
```

No other control should be adding anything directly to `Form1`. Let Form1 control it's children.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a reference to panel1 within numbers since both of them are created within form1 you can pass one as an argument to the other's constructor.

Comment: how can i reference such panel in Numbers.cs. I have a folder called UserControls and in there i have like three user controls now.. but one of them needs to change what panel1 in form1.cs has (swap to another user control).

Comment: The chain of responsibilities you propose will only complicate debugging and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your description but you can just pass the control you want in the constructor or a property. Since in C# objects are always by reference you will be action on the same control in the Button event. You can always write your own event and have the panel register for it. A more complete code sample would be great.

I'm still a little unsure of what you're doing exactly but that's OK. I think the most flexible approach is to create your own custom event. Outside of any class create a delegate:

```
public delegate void WelcomeClick(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Inside Welcome you need to create the event handler, it can be either static or part of the instance:

```
public event WelcomeClick OnClick;
```

Inside the Button Click event in welcome you can just call that event with the same parameters:

```
if (OnClick != null)
                OnClick(sender, e);
```